# How can I use the generic Apple Maps pins for locations in MapKit, rather than having to use my own images as pins?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit, mapkitannotation

In my application, I have stored coordinates in FireBase and am displaying those coordinates on a Map View in the code below. The current location of the user is also being harnessed. I would like the locations I have stored in FireBase to be represented by the generic Apple Maps pins, but I do not know how to get the app to work unless I use custom images as pins instead. Also, the generic "blue dot" of the user displayed on the map to represent the current location will not appear for me. In different projects in which the locations are stored in-app rather than in FireBase, the generic pins and blue dot appear just as I would like them to. How can I fix this?

I have tried changing bits and pieces of the code, but I am rather new to Swift and the programming world in general, and cannot find a solution.

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


@IBAction func mapSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if (sender.isOn == true) {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
    }
    else {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.hybrid
    }

}


var tappedAnnotation : MKAnnotation?

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {


    if let view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "Annotation") {
        view.annotation = annotation
         view.image = UIImage(named: "pin")
        return view
    } else {
        let view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Annotation")
        view.image = UIImage(named: "pin")
        view.isEnabled = true
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        return view
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    tappedAnnotation = view.annotation
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showAnnotationDetails", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showAnnotationDetails", let dest = segue.destination as? AnnotationDetails {
        dest.annotation = tappedAnnotation
    }
}



func createAnnotations ( _ annotations : [String:[String:Any]] ) {
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    for (_,values) in annotations {
        if let latDouble = values["latitude"] as? Double, let longDouble = values["longitude"] as? Double {
            let lat = CLLocationDegrees( latDouble )
            let long = CLLocationDegrees( longDouble )
            let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coord
            annotation.title = values["name"] as? String ?? ""
            annotation.subtitle = values["info"] as? String ?? ""
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
}

let manager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    mapView.delegate = self

    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard


    let ref = Database.database().reference()


    ref.child("annotations").observe(.value) { snapshot in 
        print(snapshot)
        if let annotations = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Any]] {
            self.createAnnotations(annotations)
        } else {
            print("Data received not formatted as expected")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `MKPinAnnotationView` instead of `MKAnnotationView`
- Set `mapView.showsUserLocation = true` to show user location (blue dot)

Comment: Thank you! The pins and location appear perfectly as I want them to. However, when I tap on the annotation, the callout button that was previously there on the custom pins as now disappeared. What is the reason for this? Thanks again.

Comment: Did you remove `view.canShowCallout = true`
        `view.rightCalloutAccessoryView` ?

Comment: I have not removed them.